# How to copy the complete folder structure (including the parent folder) through cmd in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

After trying it hard, I have not been able to copy the entire folder structure(including the parent folder and also all the contents in the folder structure) to a destination.

The folder structure is say **\path\L1\L2\sample.txt**

I need to copy the entire folder structure starting from L1 till sample.txt

This is what I have tried:

**copy \path\L1 \path\destination**

What I get at the destination is NOT the complete folder structure. In fact, I get L2\sample.txt at the destination. I want L1\L2\sample.txt at the destination.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have got this to work is by specifying the parent folder in the destination, like so:

```
xcopy /i /s \path\L1 \path\destination\L1
```

This will create output:

> \path\destination\L1\L2\sample.txt

`/i` flag is used to create the destination directory if it does not exist

`/s` flag is to copy folders and subfolders (if not empty)

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy /e \path\L1 \path\destination
```

see

```
xcopy /?
```

from the prompt for more options.

Comment: I have even gone through xcopy and I tried what you have mentioned but in this case, I am just getting the contents of L1. I also need the parent folder of L1

Comment: @Praveen: Did you try using `/e` together with `/s`? Normally, using just `/e`, as in this answer, should be enough but perhaps you are on an older version of Windows where `/e` is merely a modifier of `/s` (and so can't be used without it). I can't verify that, though.

Comment: Aha - I'd try `xcopy /e \path\L1 \path\destination\L1\` Best to show the desired destination structure rather than describing it - avoids misinterpretation to some degree.